# The position vector $\mathbf{r}$ in the electric field?

Tags: electrostatics, vectors, field-theory, coordinate-systems, vector-fields

I often see the electric field denoted \begin{align}\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})=E_x(\mathbf{r})\mathbf{\hat e}_x+E_y(\mathbf{r})\mathbf{\hat e}_y+E_z(\mathbf{r})\mathbf{\hat{e}}_z=(E_x(\mathbf{r}),E_y(\mathbf{r}),E_z(\mathbf{r}))
\end{align}
The position vector $\mathbf{r}$ confuses me.

Is $\mathbf{r}$ a *constant vector*:
$$
\mathbf{r}=x\mathbf{\hat e}_x+y\mathbf{\hat e}_y+z\mathbf{\hat{e}}_z=(x, y, z)~?
$$

Or is $\mathbf{r}$ just a abbreviation for a *vector function* of a variable, say $u$, so:
$$
\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{r}(u)=x(u)\mathbf{\hat{e}}_x+y(u)\mathbf{\hat{e}}_y+z(u)\mathbf{\hat{e}}_z=(x(u), y(u), z(u))~?
$$
Which one is correct?

Comment: VTC    insufficient research

Comment: Neither of your options makes an enormous amount of sense. Try to think about the physical meaning of a force field.

Comment: I don't understand what confuses you - do you not know what a function is? The electric field $E$ is a function of the position vector $r$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf{r}$ represents an arbitrary position in space; it is not a *constant vector*, but it can be represented by
$$
\mathbf{r}=x\mathbf{\hat e}_x+y\mathbf{\hat e}_y+z\mathbf{\hat{e}}_z=(x, y, z)
$$

Think of it as a simplified notation.